# multiplexing OV7670 video signals

Tags: multiplexer

Would it be possible to multiplex video signals transmitted from multiple cameras to a MCU? For example, can 4 OV9655 cameras modules communicate with a STM32f4 MCU?

OV9655 is a CMOS image sensor and generates 10-bits parallel video data. Other than the parallel data signals the sensor transmits 3 digital signals to the MCU, pixel clock, HSYNC, VSYNC. So if 16-bits 4:1 multiplexing is possible, then this problem would be solved.

But without using a FPGA, could one achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to read one stream at a time, or all four simultaneously?

Comment: @DaveTweed I want to receive data from one camera at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problem. Use a Buffer with three-state capability and 16bit (for example SN74AHCT16244). Then connect all same lines together and activate only the one needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWSMFq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(for simplicity only 3 bit instead of 16 are drawn)

Comment: So one needs four 16-bits 3-state buffers?

Comment: yes, one for each camera and a possibility to select one of them